# Discord.py - how do I make a command to check my bot's permissions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

How do I make a command to show what permissions my bot has in a server?
So for example, i do the command "-getperms"

Then it brings up:
✅ Manage Roles
✅ Manage Messages
✅ Manage Server

etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your permissions are accessible through [`Member.guild_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.guild_permissions).